# I am trying to write a macro which returns multiple values

Tags: excel, vba

Getting error on this line

```
Finalrow = Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(X1UP).Row
```

Error is

> Object required run time error 424.

Below is the code

```
Sub MyVlookup()
    Dim r As Long, C As Long, Col_index As Long

    Finalrow = Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(X1UP).Row
    Col_index = 2

    For I = 2 To Finalrow
        For C = 2 To 4
            Cells(I, C).Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(I, 2), Range("B2:G2"), Col_index, False)
            Col_index = Col_index + 1
        Next C
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: `X1UP` is not a thing. `Row.Count` should be `Rows.Count`. Put `Option Explicit` on top.

Comment: Thank you for editing question and for the solution. I'll let you know if it works

Answer (score 1):

```
 Finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(X1UP).Row
```

The error is on `X1UP`, I see what you tried to do, but it's actually `XlUp`, so, an L, not a 1 :) It should work with

```
 Finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(XlUp).Row
```

Comment: After writing Option Explicit, changing X1 to XL. Now I am getting error on line Sub myVlookup ()